# How to get bestselling and favorites products in rest API in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to get bestselling and favorites products from woocommerce site with rest API .

I read [this site](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs) but not found any thing about that.

Does it exist any way to get that ?

Comment: How are you identifying the bestselling and favourite products? Are you using third party plugins?

Comment: I don't create the site. I want to create android app for this site.

Comment: I can see that you can access bestsellers through reports. [See here](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-top-sellers-report). As for favourites, I think this is done using third party plugins or  custom code so I'm not sure how you are going to access this. But if I was to hazard a guess I would probably assume it would be under [customer meta](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customer-properties)

Comment: tank you for answer me

Comment: No problem. Did it resolve your issue? If it did I will post it as an answer for future.

Comment: yes I get result

Comment: Great. I've posted as an answer and would appreciate if you could mark it as answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you can access bestsellers through reports. [See here](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-top-sellers-report). As for favourites, I think this is done using third party plugins or custom code so I'm not sure how you are going to access this. But if I was to hazard a guess I would probably assume it would be under [customer meta](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customer-properties)

Comment: This only returns name and id. and there is no proper pagination. and you can't guess what is the returned count. it could be 10 or 100

Answer (score 5):

## For People Who are Still Stumbling upon this Question

As per WC v3 API. You can now pull Most Popular products through the API (which is the best selling product list as per my understanding);

`GET /wp-json/wc/v3/products?orderby=popularity&order=desc`

This should get you the most popular products in descending order by the number of sales. [This is not currently documented](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products) (as of Feb 2, 2021).

Total list of possible orderby params are: `date`, `id`, `include`, `title`, `slug`, `modified`, `menu_order`, `price`, `popularity`, `rating`

Another part of the question asks for `Favorite` product API, which woo commerce doesn't have.